# Vue - How modify this code so not new selects shows up?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

This fiddle has almost all I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjpfvx5q/1/

However I want just the first sub select to appear.
As for now, if you first select first item in main select and something from the sub select that appaears, and go back to main and select second option, then a new third selectbox is appearing.

I don't want that to happen. I just want to have one main select and a second that populates depending on choice in the first one. So just these two, no matter of how many times I reselect from the main one.

```
I am new to Vue and find it hard to see where to make that change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you select a city, you are pushing same cities into cityPacks array. No matter what, exists or not, performing this action. That populates new selectbox according to new data.

Simply, you can empty your cityPacks array before switch statement.

```
this.cityPacks = [];
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Tugayİlik's answer is correct, but in case you want to retain a 'history' of use selections in `cityPacks`, you can add a `v-if` to the second select

```html
v-if="index === coInit.map(co => co.id).indexOf(country)"
```

There's probably some other optimizations you could make to the data structures, depending on the intention of the app. For instance, it's not clear why you use `getCities` method and not just nest the cities inside the `coInit` array (and why you need to use `setTimeout`).

You could also use a `coumputed` to get the cities for the second select

```js
computed: {
  cities() {
    return this.country ? 
      ? this.country === 2 ? this.cFrance
      ? this.country === 3 ? this.cUSA
      : []
  }
},
```